# Is there a quicker way to pause Photos uploading to iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, applescript, automator, photos.app

Photos.app on Yosemite takes forever to upload its library to iCloud, and can slow the WiFi network to a crawl while it does so. I know that I can pause it in the app's Preferences, but this is complicated to explain for friends and family who are not good with computers!

I would like to make some sort of easily-accessible icon/button for pausing/unpausing the upload, that I could put on the desktop/dock/menubar.

Is there any way of doing this (for example with Automator or AppleScript)?

Answer (score 1):

From playing about with [opensnoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html), what seems to happen when you click "Pause" is that Photos (by way of cloudphotosd) adds something like the following two lines to a file within your photo library called `private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/State.plist`

```
<key>pausedUntilDate</key>
<date>2015-04-30T23:57:01Z</date>
```

However just editing that file doesn't seem to be enough, because it also seems to do something with some other binary files, for example `private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/statistics.bin`. But given that they appear to be in a binary format it's a little bit more difficult trying to work out what Photos is doing.

Here is the full trace from me running opensnoop while clicking Pause in Photos' preferences window. Maybe someone else can fill out the rest of the picture.

```
  501    395 cloudphotosd  45 ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/statistics.bin 
  501    273 Finder        36 ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine 
  501    273 Finder        36 ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/statistics.bin 
  501    273 Finder        36 ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex 
  501    273 Finder        36 ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/State.plist 
  501    273 Finder        36 ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/State.plist 
  501    273 Finder        36 ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/syncstatus.plist
```